# BLE BR/EDR Security mode

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I have recently started working on an Android-based device, which has a Murata 1MW chip. This Murata chip supports Bluetooth 5.0 + Wifi.
At present, I can open the Settings App from the Launcher and connect to any Bluetooth device.

Our requirement is -

1. The device should only support Security Mode 1 Level 4 for BLE and Security Mode 4 level 4 for BR/EDR(Classic).
2. It should only support the SPP profile.

What I understand through the readings is for Security Mode 1 Level 4 - Just works shouldn't work, but it is working on this device. It can connect directly to my headset.

I am a bit struggling to implement the above requirements -

Is there any way, through Android permissions or any changes in Android BLE/BT stack I can insert, to enforce the above requirements?
Or

Do I have to create a separate custom application to implement the above requirements?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Asma